# How can I use watin with a .HTA HTML Application?

Tags: watin, hta

I've created a .HTA HTML application and I need to be able to create test scripts for it using watin (or anything else if you can suggest something that will work and fit in well with Visual Studio Test projects).

After alot of mucking around, I'm starting to think that watin won't support .HTA files.

Can anyone help out here ?

Answer (score 0):

The anatomy of a HTA is virtually identical to HTML. It is recommended to split your CSS, VBS, JS into separate files instead of embedded it in the HTA. This will allow you to do standalone testing of your VBS, JS files in the Windows Script Host, or in unit testing HTA applications.